# Apparent Bug In Treatment of Chevrons in XSLT Output

Tags: marklogic

I have a XSLT/XQuery combination problem when there are left chevrons in the text. It seems that if I create an attribute in XSLT and put a value that contains a chevron into that attribute, then, when the output is received by XQuery, it does not escape the chevron. When I later xdmp:quote() then xdmp:unquote the XML, I get an error.

But NOT when I test this in Query Console.

This works fine if I run it in Query Console:

```
let $Q :=
  xdmp:quote(
    xdmp:xslt-eval(
      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
        <xsl:template match="A">
          <NEW>
            <xsl:attribute name="Attribute" select="normalize-space(./string())"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
          </NEW>
        </xsl:template>  
    </xsl:stylesheet> , document { <A>1 &lt; 2</A> }
              )
)
let $XML := xdmp:unquote($Q)
return  
  $XML
```

But I get this error message if the same code is run in an XQuery main module.

```
XDMP-DOCATTRVALCHAR: xdmp:unquote("<NEW Attribute=&quot;1 < 2&quot;>1 &amp;lt; 2</NEW>") -- Invalid attribute value character "<" or missing close quote at line 1
in /XSLTbugTest.xqy, at 15:12 [1.0-ml]
    $Q = "<NEW Attribute=&quot;1 < 2&quot;>1 &amp;lt; 2</NEW>"
```

When I look at the output, I see the "<" has been escaped within element content, but is still "<" in the attribute.

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are you using? Above code runs fine in 10.0-4..

Comment: I am using 10.0-6.

Comment: When I said “wrong application”, I allude to the fact that your `unquote` message doesn’t match the context of original input node. Try this in your QConsole to see if it goes through:
`xdmp:unquote("<NEW Attribute=&quot;1 &amp;lt; 2&quot;>1 &amp;lt; 2</NEW>")`     If it does, can you refactor your input node as `<A>1 &amp;lt; 2</A>` instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn’t create and import the module properly or had another wrong application of `xdmp:quote|unquote`.

To isolate the cause of the problem, you could remove the `xdmp:quote|unquote` to test the main module.

I simplified one of my modules:

```
  declare variable $reader :=
    xdmp:quote(
      xdmp:xslt-eval(
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        version="2.0">
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <BOOK author="{{distinct-values(//author)}}">
                    <xsl:sequence select="//title"/>
                </BOOK>
            </xsl:template>  
        </xsl:stylesheet>, 
       document { 
         <books>
            <book>
                <title>Sense &lt; Sensibility</title>
                <author>Jane &lt; Austen</author>
                <date>1811</date>
            </book>
            <book>
                <title>Pride &gt; Prejudice</title>
                <author>Jane &lt; Austen</author>
                <date>1813</date>
            </book>
         </books>
       }
    )
 );

declare function xsltTrans() {
    let $_ := xdmp:unquote($reader)
    return  
        $_
};
```

Then I execute the main module,

`fcTrans:xsltTrans()`

it renders the desired result (**with**|**without** `xdmp:quote|unquote`) (**in**|**out**(Java API) of QConsole):

```
<BOOK author="Jane < Austen">
    <title>Sense < Sensibility</title>
    <title>Pride > Prejudice</title>
</BOOK>
```

Comment: I already know that the problem only occurs when I DO use quote and unquote. It is the unquote that throws the error. It is essential for me to be able ot use quote and unquote for reasons outside the scope of this discussion, so avoiding their use is not an option.

I am also not sure what you mean by a "wrong application" of the module. You can confirm the problem by creating a new module that only has the code above - no need to create functions and variables - just exactly as I typed it above. You will see the error.

Comment: Why, of course, please see edit: the same result. As performance is concerned, I only use `quote|unquote` in-memory (unstructured) document as node.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that the bug only occurs when I have set the output option to "html". I had to set it to "html" because I developed an XQuery application that generated HTML pages, and doing so avoids some issues.

SO I can avoid the error if I change the output format to "xml" and solve the other problems that doing so will raise separately.

I still think it is weird that this happens though, even in "html" output mode!